# Why does my program not react to any arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argv

I have a simple test program in C++ that prints out attributes of a circle

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "circle.h" // contains the Circle class

using namespace std;

void print_circle_attributes(float r) {
    Circle* c = new Circle(r);
    cout << "radius: " << c->get_radius() << endl;
    cout << "diameter: " << c->get_diameter() << endl;
    cout << "area: " << c->get_area() << endl;
    cout << "circumference: " << c->get_circumference() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    delete c;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    float input = atof(argv[0]);
    print_circle_attributes(input);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run my program with the parameter `2.4` it outputs:

```
radius: 0.0
diameter: 0.0
area: 0.0
circumference: 0.0
```

I've previously tested the program without the parameter, but simply using static values, and it ran just fine; so I know there's nothing wrong with the class I made...

So what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Please, whatever taught you to use `new` like that, ignore it. Just write `Circle c(r);`, no `new`, no `delete`, no pointers. Magic!

Comment: Oh, and there are [good learning materials here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I use the new keyword specifically because I wanted to create the object on the heap, not on the stack, it's safer since it doesn't risk stack overflows (although a single object won't do anything, but still)

Comment: `#include "hidden_functions.h" // contains the Circle class` (proceeds to argue about the _sasfety_ of manual memory management on the free store. Yup. Oodles of sense it makes)

Comment: and why is it wrong of me to include the header that gives me access to the class in the first place?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The naming is completely at odds with the purpose. This is exmplified by the fact that you needed a comment to point out what should have been obvious (trivial comments are a code smell).

Comment: Hint: your 'solution' to stack overflow is fraught with a _lot_ more potential danger than what you were 'solving for' in the first place too. Please accept the gentle prodding of the SO [tag:c++] community as a sign that you are learning nice things :/

Comment: the purpose of the program was to test out functions that weren't declared in the header, hence the name "hidden functions"

Comment: Even if I accept the reasoning as valid, for the sake of argument, it's still not a valid justification to use new like that (there isn't any?). `std::unique_ptr`, `boost::scoped_ptr` or even `std::auto_ptr` exist for a reason.

Comment: it's a practice program, it's not doing anything serious, if it works it works

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Okay, fair enough. Next time, `#include "circle.hpp"` will convey the same information to SO readers, but taking fewer brain cycles.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee *practice* means *learning*. And what the people here are trying to tell you is that you are practicing/learning/getting used to do dangerous, unsafe thechniques (aka raw pointers) while there are better alternatives without any costs.

Comment: I'm not gonna change the displayed code now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`argv[0]` is the program name. You want `argv[1]` for the first argument.

Also, check that `argc` is at least two before trying to access it. You might also consider `std::stoi`, `std::istringstream` or `strtod` rather than `atoi` for conversion, since they can detect bogus input.

Finally, why are using `new` when an automatic variable will suffice? You should get out of that habit straight away, or spend the rest of eternity debugging memory leaks.

Comment: I used new to create the object on the heap, rather than the stack; it was done on purpose

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: When you really do need dynamic allocation (which you don't here), you should always use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/), in particular smart pointers, to bind the object to a scope and make sure the memory is released, even if an exception is thrown. But you don't need a dynamic object here at all, and using the heap when you don't need it is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 4):

`argv[0]` is the name of the executable being invoked.

Your first command line parameter will be in `argv[1]`.

To make sure that your program does not silently fail again, you should check how many parameters you actually have and if the `atof` returns a value, and show a message to the user explaining the issue accordingly.